# How to save the errors of my own listener in list?

Tags: antlr4

I am using antlr4 with web ...
 so I don't want to print the errors on consol , I search and find example to stop listener of antlr4 and add my own listener ... 
But I did not want to print the errors on consol because I my project is a web project ...
 so I think if I can save the error in list in my  own listener then I print the list on my web  page 
But I don't knew how to save the error in list into my own listener and then to get the list for print the  it on my web page ?

EDIT : 
I find this sample But I did not knew how to get the number of line and column :

```
public class DSLErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener
{
    private List<SyntaxErrorItem> items;

    public DSLErrorListener ( )
    {
        this.items = new ArrayList<SyntaxErrorItem>();
    }

    @Override
    public void syntaxError ( Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e )
    {
        items.add ( new SyntaxErrorItem ( line, charPositionInLine, msg, offendingSymbol, e ) );
    }

    public boolean hasErrors ( )
    {
        return this.items.size() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        if ( !hasErrors() ) return "0 errors";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for ( SyntaxErrorItem s : items )
        {
            builder.append ( String.format ( "%s\n", s ) );
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

class SyntaxErrorItem
{
    private int                  line;
    private Object               offendingSymbol;
    private int                  column;
    private String               msg;
    private RecognitionException oops;

    SyntaxErrorItem ( int line, int column, String msg, Object symbol, RecognitionException oops )
    {
        this.line = line;
        this.column = column;
        this.msg = msg;
        this.offendingSymbol = symbol;
        this.oops = oops;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if ( oops == null ) return String.format ( "[%d:%d] %s", line, column, msg );
        else {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter ( sw );
            oops.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.close();
            return String.format ( "[%d:%d] %s\n%s", line, column, msg, sw.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

In main :

```
Lexer lexer = ...;

CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream ( lexer );

DSLErrorListener errorListener = new DSLErrorListener();

Parser parser = ...;

parser.removeErrorListeners();

parser.addErrorListener ( errorListener );

ParseTree tree = ...; // Usually the parser subclass top-level rule name

if ( errorListener.hasErrors() ) System.err.printf( "%s\n", errorListener ); // Or parse the errors: up to you

else {

    ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker(); 

    // Walk the tree or visit it

}
```

So how I can get the number of line and column ? and there are a methode to get number of line and column and text for add errors of type checking?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You alread have everything in there. You create error items in your error listener, which is the right approach. Now simply use the list of error items. What else do you need?

Comment: the list has only the error produce by antlr ... But how I can to add the error of type checking on the same list ?? and I don't understand in code above he define (int line) But i did not knew how to get the value of line number ... the variable line has no value ??@Mike Lischke